# Redirect various query string URLs to non-query URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've seen numerous examples on how to do this with queries that have numbers (like `foo.php?id=21`). However, this redirect I'm after is for hundreds of URLs but they have the same pattern, although some key value pairs will have a `%20` in them. Here are three examples, followed by what I need them to redirect to:

`photo/search.php?keywords=foo` to `gallery/search/foo`
`photo/search.php?keywords=foo%20bar` to `gallery/search/foo-bar`
`photo/search.php?keywords=major%20foo%20bar` to `gallery/search/major-foo-bar`

I'm just not sure how to do this for hundreds of URLs.

[edit - added below]

Here's what I have that is mostly working now:

```
# Recursively replace spaces with hyphens until there are none left
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?%1-%2 [E=NOSPACE:1]
# When there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^photo/search\.php$ /gallery/search/%1? [L,R=301]
```

My new problem is that if there is more than one space, the second % sign is getting encoded too, so the redirected URL ends up being wrong. Example:

this: `http://example.com/photo/search.php?keywords=some%20keywords%20here`

goes to this: `http://example.com/gallery/search/some-keywords%2520here`

but it should go to this: `http://example.com/gallery/search/some-keywords-here`

Comment: Please share what you have  tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /photo/search\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keywords=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?photo/search.php$ /gallery/search/%1? [NE,R,L]

RewriteRule ^/?gallery/search/([^/]+)$ /photo/search.php?keywords=$1 [L]
```

Line 1 - 3 : check the request line `(e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1")`, the request path is `/photo/search.php`, and if contains the query string `keywords=`, redirect the request uri from `/photo/search.php` to `/gallery/search/%1?`, `%1` is the back-reference to `([^&]+)`, and `?` remove any query string.

Line 4: internal rewrite the URL from `/gallery/search/([^/]+)` to `/photo/search.php?keywords=$1`, `$1` is the back reference to `([^/]+)`.

You may need some help from php script, if spaces detected from keywords, redirect to the dash one.

```
if (isset($_GET['keywords']) && stripos($_GET['keywords'], ' ') !== false) {
    header('location: /gallery/search/' . urlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['keywords'])));
    exit;
}
```